# How to use reverse in foreach of XmlNodeList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml-parsing, foreach

I want to get the data in reverse from foreach

Here `XmlNodeList comments = d.SelectNodes("//comments/comment/creator");`

I've 4 values,I want to reverse it

I've written this code

```
 public void commentM4(string pstId, string cmtId)
    {
        XmlDocument d = new XmlDocument();
        d.LoadXml(content);

        XmlNodeList comments = d.SelectNodes("//comments/comment/creator");
        foreach (XmlNode xncomment in  comments)
        {
            commentMemberId = xncomment["id"].InnerText;
            DbConnection.Open();
            DbCommand = new OleDbCommand("select count(response_id) from  mw_response where customer_id = '" + commentMemberId + "' AND post_id='" + pstId + "'", DbConnection);
            OleDbDataReader DbReader = DbCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (DbReader.Read())
            {
                count = DbReader[0].ToString();
                cnt = Convert.ToInt32(count);
                if ((cnt == 0) && (comments1 != ""))
                {
                    DbCommand = new OleDbCommand("update mw_response set prod_id = (select prod_id from mw_post where post_id='" + pstId + "'),customer_id = (select customer_id from mw_customer where customer_id='" + commentMemberId + "') where response_id = '" + cmtId + "'", DbConnection);
                    DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            DbReader.Close();
            DbConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `for` loop instead, that starts at the last element, and works its way back to the first.

```
if (comments.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = (comments.Count - 1); i >= 0; i--)
    {
     XmlNode xncomment = comments[i];
    //Rest of the logic...
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I've added an if-block to make sure that the loop only runs if there is more than one element in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

This helps you:

public static string ReverseString(string s)
    {
    char[] arr = s.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(arr);
    return new string(arr);
    }

Comment: OP is not working with strings or arrays. He has an XmlNodeList, which doesn't have a ToArray() method. Also, writing a method that just calls another method seems overkill for this purpose.